# How to compare value with total calculation of a column in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]

I am trying to compare values with the total of Avgofsales but it compares with each row of Avgofsales.

I have created the below measure:

Measure = if([SumofSales]>[Avgofsales],[SumofSales],BLANK())

Comment: Avgofsales = CALCULATE([SumofSales]/DISTINCTCOUNT(DimStore[StoreName]))  this measure is for Avgofsales  column

Comment: Better: Avgofsales = DIVIDE ( [SumofSales], DISTINCTCOUNT ( DimStore[StoreName] ) )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Avgofsales > Total = 
var rowavg = 
    AVERAGE('Table'[Avgofsales])
var totalavg =
    CALCULATE(
        AVERAGE('Table'[Avgofsales]),
        ALL('Table')
    )
RETURN
    IF( rowavg > totalavg, rowavg, Blank())
```

The result will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this measure:

```
Measure00 =
VAR Avgofsales =
    AVERAGEX ( ALL ( DimStore[StoreName] ), [SumofSales] )
RETURN
    IF ( [SumofSales] > Avgofsales, [SumofSales], BLANK () )
```